# Android: Load in background some images in a WebView cache them and than load from cache in a second webview

Tags: java, android, caching, webview

How can I do to load some images in a webview and save them in cache. I need this because when the user turn the page and need to view the second page the second webview can use the img stored in cache by the 1st webview that has loaded them in background.

That's the only configuration that I do on my 2 webview

```
    webViewImageCache = (WebView)v.findViewById(R.id.webViewImageCache);
    webview = (WebView)v.findViewById(R.id.webView);

    //Caching
    webViewImageCache.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT);
    webview.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT);
```

Comment: simply load the img in the second webview and than load them in the 1st webview but it seems that the 1st webview re-download those images. Anyway if is the 1st webview to load the images I seems that it can store them in cache... what I think I need is a shared cache.

Comment: You should post your code so we can see what you've tried and then identify the problem.

Comment: make an edit to my question